# Keyboard pushes up my footer tab in Android - Titanium

Tags: android, titanium

I have a Navigation header, a TextField inside a Scroll view and a Footer Tab.
When keyboard appears, it pushes up my Footer Tab.

To fix this problem I added **windowSoftInputMode** to my window.

```
"#baseWindow[platform=android]": {
      windowSoftInputMode: Titanium.UI.Android.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN
}
```

It fixed the Footer Tabs pushing up issue. But, it makes my Navigation Header to Pushed up. How can I solve this issue without effecting my Navigation Header?

Answer (score 0):

Here I solved my issue.

I hide my Footer Tab when the keyboard appears.

```
$.getView().addEventListener("postlayout", adjustFooterTab);

function adjustFooterTab() {
    if (Ti.Platform.osname == 'android') {
        var deviceHeight = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight / (Ti.Platform.displayCaps.dpi / 160);
        Ti.API.info('deviceHeight::' + deviceHeight + ", window height::" + $.question.rect.height);
        if (deviceHeight > $.question.rect.height + 100) {
            Ti.API.info('keypad shown');
            $.tabs.visible = false;
            $.tabs.height = 0;
            $.scrollView.bottom = 0;
        } else {
            Ti.API.info('keypad hide');
            $.tabs.visible = true;
            $.tabs.height = "55dp"; 
            $.scrollView.bottom ="55dp";
        }
    }
}
```